# How to get kmalloc physical address in app?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

1, In driver, I use kmalloc memory, and implement mmap, in mmap, i use remap_pfn_range to map.

2, In app, I use mmap get the memory, and use /proc/self/pagemap get physical address, but it's wrong.

why?

Comment: Implement a ioctl to your driver and pass the physical address to user space and then you can map it

Comment: It sounds like you're doing the right sort of thing, however without more detail we can't tell what's going wrong. You need to add a small piece of code which is just enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I think remap_pfn_range don't affect /proc/self/pagemap.